# How to call non-static method using laravel alias

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a custom helper class and ill set the alias for that class for access to the blade file(frontend). I can access the static methods referring to the alias::method but I need to access the nonstatic methods from the view. how can I do that?

```
'Access' => App\Services\Access::class,
Two functions in Access class.
public function getPermissions()
public static function getUser()
```

I can easily access the static function using `Access::getUser()`
So How can access the non-static functions?

Comment: you would need an instance of the class to be able to call the non static methods ... perhaps you would like a Facade for this class instead or have the magic `__callStatic` method create a new instance and call the method on it for you

Comment: @lagbox thank you. that's the point. can you share some code or URL, please?

Comment: can you provide the code where you are trying to use this?

Comment: I need to call getPermissions() function from view. through the Access alias.

Comment: but below you said you need it in a custom blade directive ... which is it?

Comment: yes. ill implement it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access it in your view, you can share a new instance of Access to all your views :

In the boot() method of your AppServiceProvider :

```
View::share('access', (new App\Services\Access));
```

then in your blade `@foreach($access->getPermissions() as $permission)`

Comment: no. I don't need to use the view share because I want to access the nonstatic method inside the custom blade directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject an instance of this class into your view:

```
@inject('access', Access::class)
```

Now you can access all those methods via `$access->whatEverMethod()`. Otherwise you will need a Facade or deal with the magic methods to call the non static method on the class itself.